# On irreducibility of intersection of quadrics in $\mathbb P^3$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

We know that intersection of two hyperplane in $\mathbb P^3$ is a line  and hence irreducible.Can the same statement be generalized in case of hypersurfaces?

In particular my question is :Is the intersection of an hyperplane with an irreducible quadric In $\mathbb P^3$ an irreducible curve?

And what about intersection of two irreducible quadrics?

It seems it's not true in general.

Can somebody give me a concrete counterexample or may be under what conditions the intersection is irreducible.

Any help from anyone is welcome

Comment: Intersect a quadric with a tangent plane.

Comment: What have you tried? For instance, have you looked at the construction of classical conic sections by intersecting a plane with a cone? Your second question is also a repeat of a portion of [your question from yesterday](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3513499/on-quadrics-in-mathbb-p3) with no new information. Did you try anything there?

Comment: @KReiser, If both the quadrics are union of hyperplanes then the intersection is union of $4$ lines.But in other cases when both of them are irreducible quadric it's not clear to me how the irreducible components look like leading to the last question.When one of them is a union of hyperplanes and other one is an irreducible quadric then the intersection is union of curves of degree $2$ ,which I don't know are irreducible or not leading to the first question.